# How to solder a micro USB port with chipped pads?

Tags: pcb, soldering, repair

What are the strategies for soldering a micro USB port which has broken and chipped-away pads? See the picture for details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In this case it looks like the data wires are not connected to anything. Is this what you expect? Because if I'm right, that makes it a lot easier

Comment: You are right. So what you are saying is that since its only a "charging port", tracing those two lines and directly connecting a jumper wire to where ever it leads, will make it usable again. Correct?  (I have added another picture)

Comment: Those are tiny traces, you can't do stuff like charging a battery through those. You can however supply a PCB from there if it doesn't draw a lot of current.

Comment: This is a mini router and above comments are correct that it is a charging port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clean the holes out, and clean all the peeled copper off the connector itself (or, better, use a new connector). Clean the board of flux with 99% isopropanol so you can see what you are doing.

Put it in the holes and solder as well as you can. Then gently scrape the solder mask off the copper in the areas shown (without removing the copper) using an Xacto knife, and tin the areas.

[image]

Jumper the end connections to the copper as shown with thin wires (maybe ~AWG30).

When you are sure it is working reliably, further secure the connector with a bit of epoxy, taking care not to get it into the connector. A tiny bit on the two data lines (the middle ones) to keep them from moving wouldn't hurt.

It may be tempting to jumper directly to the end of that long thing to reduce the amount of scraping, but I'd be a bit careful around that unless you have a well controlled soldering iron (doubt) since it might be a fuse and it could be easily ruined by excessive heat.